# Closed orientable $n$-manifold $X$, there's a map $f: S^n \to X$ of nonzero degree, $n > 1$, is $\pi_1(X)$ finite?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

A closed orientable $n$-manifold $X$ satisfies $(*)$ if there is some map $f: S^n \to X$ of nonzero degree (i.e. for which the image of the generator of $H_n(S^n)$ is equal to a nonzero multiple of the generator of $H_n(X)$). If $X$ satisfies $(*)$ and $n > 1$, does it follow that $\pi_1(X)$ is finite?

Comment: Yes, since since it factors through the universal cover. Actually the universal cover of the codomain must be homotopy equivalent to the sphere, thus by Poincare homeomorphic.

Comment: @MikeMiller I posted an almost same solution.

Comment: My mistake above. The actual result is that the universal cover of the codomain has the same homology as the sphere with rational coefficients or $\Bbb F_p$ coefficients where $p$ is coprime to the degree of the map to the universal cover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the universal cover of $X$. Then since $n>1$ the map $f$ has a lift $\bar{f}$ to the universal cover $Y$. If $\pi_1(X)$ is infinite, then $Y$ would be non-compact. And $f=p\circ \bar{f}$ where $p$ be the universal covering map.  And since the map $f$ is factored through $Y$, so $f_*:H_n(S^n)\to H_n(X)$ will be factored through $H_n(Y)$ which is $0$  (since $Y$ is non-compact, the $n-th$ homology of $Y$ is zero by the version of Poincare Duality of non-compact space). This implies $deg(f)=0$.

Thus if $deg(f)\neq 0$, then $\pi_1(X)$ has to be finite.

Comment: As far as I know "degree" is only defined for maps between compact manifolds. Do you have a reference justifying your use of degree in the case of a non-compact manifold like $Y$ ?

Comment: @Georges The map factors through the universal cover. If the universal cover is noncompact, its top homology is zero, and the degree of the composite is zero.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg  see in any case the map $f$ will be factored through the universal cover. I might use some abuse of notation, so let me edit it.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Have a look.

Comment: Dear Anubhav (and @Mike) : yes, you are right. My nitpicking was that you have to use homology and not the degree theory of compact oriented manifolds as developed in courses on differential manifolds, like that of Guillemin-Pollack. That said your proof is elegant and concise: bravo and +1.